# Magento omits my javascript files when I merge

Tags: javascript, css, magento, merge

I'm trying to merge my javascript in Magento panel.

- Merge JS [YES]
- Protocol Relative URLs [YES]

But when I set this, (clear cache in magento), and reload the page. My JS links desappear in the source code of the my shop, and JS crashes.
On the other side, if I do this with my css it works.

---

I also saw that my js files are like this:

```
path/to/js/menu.12347636.js
```

And my css files looks like:

```
path/to/css/boxes.css
```

Maybe this is the problem and magento don't recognize the files, but I don't know whi this happens.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: When you are not merging, how do you include these files to your page(s)?

Comment: Merging your Js may cause errors that cause it to break, check your console. Also the CSS merged file should have a similar name so it looks like that's not working.

Comment: @adrien54 the files are included via xml in "page.xml" and are stored in skin/frontend/myStore/default/js/

Comment: Hi @WombleGold, yes but the thing is that when I merge, Magento stops calling them, and they dissappear from the source code in the web inspector.

Comment: Can you see if the merged JS files are actually being created in media/js folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:
"My JS links disappear in the source code of the my shop, and JS crashes."

I think actually your JS crashes first, then your function can't be executed.

The JS files don't really disappear from your source code, they are all merged in one file that should be named like:

```
/media/js/4dbb3c5d88be6727249b913787054d41.js
```

So I guess you must have an error in this file.
The main error while merging is missing semi-colons `;` at the end of some files. Here an example of what is happening:

File `A.js`

```
... })
```

File `B.js`

```
Validation.defaultOptions = ...
```

Files Merged `4dbb3c5d88be6727249b913787054d41.js`

```
... })Validation.defaultOptions = ...
//Missing ; at the end of file A throws an error in merged file.
```

You should have a JS error in the Console to help you debug that.